# Json parsing in an Android application

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am new in Json parsing. I am receiving Json data from my url which is given below:

```
[
    [
        {
            "message": "hdjcjcjjckckckckvkckckck",
            "timetoken": 14151866297757284
        },
        {
            "message": "ufjfjfjcjfjchfjdhwjroritkgjcj",
            "timetoken": 14151869212145692
        },
        {
            "message": "udjfjfudjcyshdhsnfkfkvkf",
            "timetoken": 14151869317015766
        },
        {
            "message": "lvkifjsywjfwhsjvjdjfudjgidufkg",
            "timetoken": 14151869404695072
        },
        {
            "message": "ifjfydncydhsxhshfjdjejtlfudj",
            "timetoken": 14151869494732788
        },
        {
            "message": "22637485969473849506&#&#*%-&+",
            "timetoken": 14151869589393336
        },
        {
            "message": "jcjfjdueywjfusufig",
            "timetoken": 14151869671994892
        },
        {
            "message": "ofkdiriflfkkkfkdiidk",
            "timetoken": 14151869775170644
        },
        {
            "message": "testing",
            "timetoken": 14151869895179728
        },
        {
            "message": 1234567,
            "timetoken": 14151869986900556
        },
        {
            "message": 9877653,
            "timetoken": 14151870106439620
        },
        {
            "message": "zxcvbnmmkljgdaqerip",
            "timetoken": 14151870236042386
        }
    ],
    14151866297757284,
    14151870236042386
]
```

I am using this to break JsonArray data into different index like I want to display message and timetoken in separate lines in my activity, like this:

```
message: hdjcjcjjckckckckvkckckck
time token: 14151866297757284
message: 22637485969473849506&#&#*%-&+
time token: 14151869212145693
```

What should I have to do in the following line of codes:

```
JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(message.toString());  //message.toString() is the Json Response data
for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {

}
```

I want to display it in my `Textview` as described above.

Comment: Use Gson. https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 1):

Try this one (not tested):

```
JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(message.toString());  //message.toString() is the Json Response data
JSONArray array =  jsonObj.getJSONArray(0);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject item = array.getJSONObject(i);
  String mesage = item.getJsonString("message");
  String timespan = item.getJsonString("timespan");
}
```

Comment: It is not working @Roman. I have solved it. Actually it was a double array, like Json Array > JsonArray > JsonObject. try {
JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(message.toString()); 
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonObj.get(0).toString());
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
String messageString=c.getString("message");
String timeString=c.getString("timetoken");
}
}

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. Actually the Json string has double Json Array and then Json Object.

I was doing a mistake to send an object of Json Array to Json Object. Now I have make an object of Json Array1 then send it to Json Array2 and then send the object of Json Array2 in `Json Object`.

The code is given below:

```
try {

        JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(message.toString()); 
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonObj.get(0).toString());
                                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String messageString=c.getString("message");
        String timeString=c.getString("timetoken");
        String abc = timeString;

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should put json parsing into try-catch block:

```
try{
    JSONArray res = new JSONArray(response.toString());
    JSONArray jsonArray = res.getJSONArray(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String message = object.getString("message");
        String token = object.getString("timetoken");
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

you have a double array, so you have two JSONArray. Actually, JSONArray usually marked by [] and JSONObject marked by {}.

In other words `{}`=`JSONObject` and `[]`=`JSONArray`.